# .NET Core 3.1 Docker in Visual Studio accessing Azure Key Vault

Tags: visual-studio, azure, docker, azure-keyvault

I am trying to run a .NET Core 3.1 Application in Docker locally in Visual Studio. The application needs to access a Azure Key Vault.

When I run the application I get the following error:

> One or more errors occurred. (Parameters: Connection String: [No
> connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net,
> Authority:
> https://login.windows.net/53d4d1e1-3360-4735-8aad-21c6155f528a.
> Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access
> token, but none of them worked.
>
> Parameters: Connection String: [No
> connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net,
> Authority:
> https://login.windows.net/53d4d1e1-3360-4735-8aad-21c6155f528a.
> Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity.
> Access token could not be acquired. Connection refused
>
> Parameters:
> Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource:
> https://vault.azure.net, Authority:
> https://login.windows.net/53d4d1e1-3360-4735-8aad-21c6155f528a.
> Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access
> token could not be acquired. Environment variable LOCALAPPDATA not
> set.
>
> Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified],
> Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority:
> https://login.windows.net/53d4d1e1-3360-4735-8aad-21c6155f528a.
> Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token
> could not be acquired. /bin/bash: az: No such file or directory

Note: it works fine using IIS Express! Please help! :D

Comment: Where is the code? Also cleanup the message so that we can read them - a big block of text is hard to read.

Comment: What do you mean sorry? The code is running in the docker container locally on my machine...?

Comment: I believe you need to be running VS in a user context that has access to the Key Vault so that it can acquire a token.

Comment: The accepted answer is insecure because it has you store sensitive information in a file that should be checked in to source control (and it kind of defeats the purpose of using Key Vault in the first place); instead I've posted an [alternate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526400/398630) below that you should consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set the required [environment variables](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity#environment-variables) when using DefaultAzureCredential to authenticate Azure key vault.

In this scenario, it means to set the environment variables in Dockerfile.

```
ENV AZURE_CLIENT_ID=<Your AZURE CLIENT ID>
ENV AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=<Your CLIENT SECRET>
ENV AZURE_TENANT_ID=<Your TENANT ID>
```

Comment: Storing the client secret in a public configuration file is a big no-no, and it defeats the purpose of using Azure Key Vault in the first place; instead consider the alternative answer that I have [posted below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526400/398630).

Answer (score 1):

In an attempt to avoid the accepted answer (because of obvious security issues), and to simplify and automate [E. Staal's answer (on a duplicate question)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61498506/398630), I came up with this:

1. Update your `.gitignore` file, by adding the following line to the bottom of it:

   ```
   appsettings.local.json
   ```
2. Right click on the project in Solution Explorer, and click on `Properties`; in the `Build Events` tab, find the `Pre-build event command line` text box and add the following code:

   ```
   cd /d "$(ProjectDir)"
   if exist "appsettings.local.json" del "appsettings.local.json"
   if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Debug" (
   az account get-access-token  --resource=https://vault.azure.net > appsettings.local.json
   )
   ```
3. In your `launchSettings.json` (or using the Visual Editor under project settings) configure the following values:

   ```json
   {
     "profiles": {
       // ...
       "Docker": {
         "commandName": "Docker",
         "environmentVariables": {
           "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
           "AZURE_TENANT_ID": "<YOUR-AZURE-TENANT-ID-HERE>"
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
4. In your `Program.cs` file find the CreateHostBuilder method and update the  `ConfigureAppConfiguration` block accordingly -- here is mine as an example:

   ```cs
   Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureAppConfiguration
   (
       (ctx, cfg) =>
       {
           if (ctx.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
           {
               cfg.AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.json", true);
           }

           var builtConfig = cfg.Build();
           var keyVault = builtConfig["KeyVault"];
           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyVault))
           {
               var accessToken = builtConfig["accessToken"];
               cfg.AddAzureKeyVault
               (
                   $"https://{keyVault}.vault.azure.net/",
                   new KeyVaultClient
                   (
                       string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accessToken)
                       ? new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback
                       (
                           new AzureServiceTokenProvider().KeyVaultTokenCallback
                       )
                       : (x, y, z) => Task.FromResult(accessToken)
                   ),
                   new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager()
               );
           }
       }
   )
   ```

If this still doesn't work, verify that `az login` has been performed and that `az account get-access-token  --resource=https://vault.azure.net` works correctly for you.